# i'm facing an issue regarding the media3 exo player controlls position in a horizoantal tab

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer, android-media3

i'm making a video player in jetpack compsoe using media3 exo player. thae problem i'm facing is that in a horizontal tab mode i give an aspect ration of 16/9f to my player and defined 60% of total screen width for the player so the default controlls should be visible inside the defined 60% width but they are visible in the end of screen or outside the defined area for the video player. i'm using media3 version 1.2.1 and all latest version of dependencies
i'm mentioning the screenshots for my problem

I'm using media 3 exo player